# How to attach uploaded files in Google Drive to another email

Tags: gmail, google-drive

I have files uploaded to my Google Drive.

I want to send an email and attach to it one of my already uploaded files, without having to upload the file again. The file is classified as public.

How do I attach the already uploaded file to this new email?

Answer (score 0):

When composing the message, mouse over the attachment icon (paper clip). You should get a fly-out menu. The second option is the Google Drive icon. Click it.

That'll give you a menu to be able to choose any file from your "My Drive" in Google Drive. Choose what you want and "Insert". (You can choose multiple files at a go or re-open the menu multiple times.)

See also: [Official Gmail Blog: Attachments in Gmail, now with the power of Google Drive](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/11/attachments-in-gmail-now-with-power-of.html)